# Paging a Horizontal Barchart with too many columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a barchart which is oriented horizontally.  Usually it is ok but if 
there are too many items, then it gets all cramped up.  So I need to set a 
cut off point of say 10 items, after which the remainder will be put on a 
new page.   Here is an image of the chart....

[image: too many columns]

What I have done so far is to add a List control and specify the Grouping as
    =Floor((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/10)

but it appears that some data is missing as the Dataset returns many rows for
an item and uses Average and other functions to create the items.

There is also a PageBreak property for the chart element and it has a 'BreakLocation'
one selection of which is 'Between', but it doesn't seem to do anything, as there
is no where to specify 'between what' it would make the pagebreak.

Any ideas.  I have searched the web and found only 2 references to this, one which 
uses the List Item grouping and another which references some sample code from a book
which uses an old version of Visual studio.

Comment: Can you supply a sample Dataset? Then we can test with representative data. Adding some DDL into a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example would be the best option here.

Answer (score 0):

Drag a List control on the page, click on it and go to Tablix properties and set it to the same dataset as the chart.  Then go to the grouping section and choose 'Group Properties', I added this under 'Row Groups' Click Add under 'Group expressions'  and use an expression to group...like =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/10)